# apt-get install not work at all

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, 15.04

when i use command `sudo apt-get install git` it's return below erorrs and it's return for any application to install below :

```
Setting up util-linux (2.25.2-4ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/nodejs': Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

update with `sudo apt-get update` not working and report below erorr

```
Fetched 7,032 kB in 5min 32s (21.2 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/paullo612/unityshell-rotated/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/paullo612/unityshell-rotated/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

how can fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two, unrelated errors. The first one is that the file `/usr/bin/nodejs`, which belongs to package `nodejs`, seems to be broken. Uninstalling and/or reinstalling that package may fix the issue.

The second is that you have enabled a repository which no longer exists. You need to remove that repository from your list of repositories, either through whatever GUI tool you are using or by removing it from your `sources.list`.

Comment: To remove the [PPA](http://askubuntu.com/q/343333/58950), you can also follow this advice: http://askubuntu.com/a/91660/58950