# repository and update but what then..

Tags: software-installation, updates, repository

my issue being..

when looking into a program and when i deside to install there is often the following two lines available.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:#######.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update

which i prosume the program is added in the repository and then update (all) the programs in the repository including the new to be installed program that then is installed.

but after that i fail to actually start the intended program, or look it up under search. in this particular case inkscape..

i also tried (afterwards) to install via ubuntu software but it stops at 9%, could be because it is already installed but also had issues with ubuntu software so i prefered the install via terminal

strangely enough sometimes the program does appear in time. so i also rebooted but that doesn't work either.

what am i doing wrong / not doing here.

Kind regards

Comment: oke, thank you both, i know it had to be something like that. But i actually tried it but it failed. so i assumed it was my error but maybe it goes deeper than that.  what i did now it the following. i manually removed the ppa in : system-settings/software&update/other software.

Comment: afterwards i run: sudo apt-get autoremove & sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq inkscape.(inkscape was not being installed) rebooted and tried to install via software centre but it still stuck@ 9%.  re-added the ppa (via search), updating and install.  it now finally works...  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So step 1 is adding the repo

Step 2 is to update and finally

Step 3 is to install

An example of this is the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine
```

The adding of the repository enables you access to said repository.

The update performed after is so that your system recognizes the changes that have been made. The change in this case being the addition of a repository.

The install command run afterwords is what actually installs the program.

In short adding a repo and updating the system doesn't auto install the program you want. You still need to apt-get install it.

I suggest that you try and uninstall the program, remove the repo and repeat the steps I've listed. Or simply go through the software center. It's possible that something broke during your install. We'd need some terminal output to assist further.

There is a difference between repositories and PPA (Personal Package Archives). Please see this link for more information regarding them. 
[What's the difference between a PPA and a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343333/whats-the-difference-between-a-ppa-and-a-repository)

Comment: Consider a reminder for new users that software in the Ubuntu repos are community-supported while PPAs are usually not. Some confused new users don't understand the difference.

Answer (score -1):

extensive answer

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wrinkliez/ppasearch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppasearch`

inkscape instead of ppasearch in your case

`https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them`